# Seeking podcasts related to geospatial technologies?

Tags: references, podcast

I would like to make a list of podcasts related to geospatial technologies.

Do you listen to any that you find interesting and informative?

Answer (score 5):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
> and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
> should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

Here is a [list](https://geoawesomeness.com/geospatial-podcasts/) created by Geoawesomeness with geospatial podcasts. It includes the following podcasts:

- [VerySpatial](http://veryspatial.com/)
- [Geodorable](https://geodorable.com/)
- [The Mappyist Hour](http://The%20Mappyist%20Hour)
- [Speaking of GIS](https://speakingofgis.com/)
- [Mapscaping](https://mapscaping.com/blogs/the-mapscaping-podcast)
- [Scene from Above](http://scenefromabove.org/)
- [Directions Magazine](https://player.fm/series/directions-magazine-podcasts)
- [Cageyjames & Geobabbler](https://cng.fireside.fm/)
- [Geographical Imaginations](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/geographical-imaginations/id1386704057?mt=2)
- [Women and Drones](http://womenanddrones.libsyn.com/)
- [Esri & The Science of Where Podcast](https://www.esri.com/about/newsroom/podcast/)
- [Where 2.0 Podcasts](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/where2.0.html)
- [gotgeoint](http://www.blogtalkradio.com/gotgeoint)
- [Farallon Geographics podcasts](http://www.fargeo.com/podcasts/)
- [Location Matters](https://ngis.com.au/Newsroom/Podcast)
- Training_Data which is a series made by CosmiQ works.

Also, there are other interesting podcasts that have some geospatial-related episodes. For example. there's Stats and Stories with [this episode](https://statsandstories.net/environment1/statistical-mapping) and Data Skeptic with [this one](https://dataskeptic.com/blog/episodes/2019/mapping-dialects-with-twitter-data). These two podcasts are really well made and their format is very nice because episodes are no longer than 30 minutes.