# Recommendations for geospatial podcasts

Tags: podcast

Podcasting seems to be exploding these days but I was wondering if anyone has come across a podcast or podcasts explores the stuff that is happening out there in the geospatial world?

I have found one that a really like "[The MapScaping Podcast](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-mapscaping-podcast/id1452297085?mt=2)" but I would love to hear if anyone out there that has any other recommendations.

Comment: Duplicate?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/671/43